# If condition not matching inside a foreach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I just finished my Powershell training of 10961 and trying to create my scripts.

Currently I am working on a very simple script which connects to a vCenter server and starts VM if powered off.

```
# List of VMs
$VMs = "VM001","VM002","VM003"

# Retrieve VM state
$VM = Get-VM -Name $VMs

foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    if ($VM.PowerState -ne "PoweredOn") {
        Start-VM -VM $vm -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host "$vm is starting"
    }        
    else {
        Write-Host "$vm is already Powered On" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

At lease one of these VMs is powered off but the script reports all as Powered On.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try inspecting the value on the objects returned by `Get-VM`: `Get-VM -Name $VMs |Select Name,PowerState`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
PowerState values are displayed as: PoweredOn, PoweredOff however when I tried to power on a already powered on VM the error displayed in console is Can not be performed in the current state "Powered On" I add space in my script and it works now.